# How to show starting time and ending time in list when clicking different buttons in android

Tags: java, android

I developing an application to show the real time information in RecyclerlistView.

My application contains 4 buttons, when clicking on first button it get the current system time and store in array  and when clicking on 2nd button the current time should be the end time of first button and the same function for all the buttons
Here is my sample image. r[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: The above image in sample data what i need...What i required  in my application is ,My app contains 4 buttons like offduty, onduty,sleep and driving state.when driver clicking on the offduty button we should store the current time and endtime of that state when he changed the state by clicking on onduty button then the end time of offduty should be starting time of onduty and again while changing the state by clicking other button like sleep the starting time should be end time of previous button(onduty) and based on start time and end time we can calculate no of hours. tq

Comment: i had created for arraylist for 4 params .... if (str_on.equals("offdrive")){
                    starttime.add(currenttime);
                    endtime.add("");
                    hoursinfo.add("2");
                    statearray.add(btn_offduty.getText().toString());
                    prepareDrivingData();

Comment: You just need to update the list? How about using the notifyDataSetChanged?